# Convert CString to LPCVOID

Tags: visual-c++

I am looking for a straightforward answer. There doesn't seem to be one on the net. Maybe because its not possible. How on earth do you convert CString to LPCVOID?? I haven;t tried much yet, as there is no suggestion of what to do on the web....if this is not possible is there a way to convert CString to char *?? For this i have tried everything that has been suggested on the net and nothing works.

For eg:

```
CString s("1000");
CStringA str(s);
char* something = (LPSTR)(LPCSTR)str;
```

None of the 20 so methids i think iv'e tried have worked. Please help.

Thanking you kindly.

Comment: CString::GetBuffer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314880(v=vs.60).aspx should be a good start

Comment: What do you want the LPCVOID to be pointing at? The CString object is not the same thing as the string inside it. It is also impossible to answer your question about converting to char* without specifying whether the CString contains char's or wchar_t's.

Answer (score 1):

The question as asked doesn't make any sense. Find out what the caller actually wants - LPCVOID is just a pointer type which means "points to anything whatsoever". The function that is called actually expects that the pointer will point to data in some format.

The caller must provide the data in the format that the callee expects; you have to write code to do that, but first you must read the documentation of the callee because if you don't know what it expects, how can you pass that data?

CString is some kind of non-standard C++ class (probably some Microsoft invention), so you need to read its documentation to find out how to extract whatever data you need to extract. I'm quite sure that casting won't do anything useful.